# Router in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been learning React for a few days. Everything has been going fine, but today I got this error.

Error in ./~/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js
Module parse failed: /home/sunny/Desktop/react-tut/reactjourney/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js Unexpected token (1307:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1307:8)
@ ./~/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js 12:125-153

```
and my App.jsx will look like this 

import './App.css';

import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function App(){

  return(

    <div className="App"> 

      <h1>hello react router  6</h1>

      <BrowserRouter>

        <Routes>

          <Route path='/home' element={<h1> hey this is home </h1>} />
        </Routes>


      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I'm learning router in react js, but got an error and I find the solution for that!

Comment: You've a typo. The imported `Router` component should be the `Routes` component. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A visible issue that I see in the code is that the inside `<BrowserRouter>` component should be the `<Routes>` component not `<Router>`. This could cause the error you are facing.

This code is working for me just fine:

```js
import "./App.css";

import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> hello react router 6 </h1>

      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={<h1> hey this is home </h1>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Sandbox Link:

[image: Edit React withClickOutside (forked)]

Comment: Buddy my error didn't solve ??

Comment: Sorry to hear that the issue is still persisting. I think it's related to your environment, as your code is working perfectly after fixing the typo in the sandbox. Can you provide some additional information about your environment, like your package.json file, so that we can understand the issue better?